# Confusion with std::vector::size_type

Tags: c++, stdvector, unordered-map

Given the code snippet

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unordered_map<int, vector<int>> mem{{1, {2,3,4,5}}, {2, {6,7,8,9}}};
    int maxVal = 0;

    for (auto it = mem.begin(); it != mem.end(); ++it)
    {
        maxVal = max(maxVal, (it->second).size());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this returns the compilation error

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:23:49: error: no matching function for call to ‘max(int&, std::vector::size_type)’
   21 |         maxVal = max(maxVal, (it->second).size());
      |                                                 ^
```

But if I change this to

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unordered_map<int, vector<int>> mem{{1, {2,3,4,5}}, {2, {6,7,8,9}}};
    int maxVal = 0;

    for (auto it = mem.begin(); it != mem.end(); ++it)
    {
        vector<int> v = it->second;
        int vSize = v.size();
        maxVal = max(maxVal, vSize);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

where I have explicitly created a vector held by the map's value, then this works correctly. Similarly, if I change `maxVal = max(maxVal, (it->second).size());` to something like `cout << (it->second).size()` then it also compiles and works without error.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: both parameters passed to `max` need to have the same time.  `vector::size_type` is generally `std::size_t`.

Comment: The vector size type is an *unsigned* type. Typically an alias for `std::size_t` (which in turn often is an alias for `unsigned long`). The type `int` is *signed*.